# \cleardoublepage not working with tex4ebook

Tags: tex4ebook

Below is my mwe that creates text on pages 1, 3, and 5 when I build a PDF from my `main.text`. When I run `tex4ebook -l main.tex` to build my epub, it puts all the text on a single page. Is there an alternative to `\cleardoublepage` that I should use to put the text on odd numbered pages?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
This is page one.
\cleardoublepage
This is page three.
\cleardoublepage
This is page five.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the method from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311387/2891) should work, with a little modification (change `\clearpage` to `\cleardoublepage`)

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks! That worked great except it it gives me a single page break instead of always starting on an odd page. (I just swapped out all the "clearpage"s with "cleardoublepage" in the config file). BUT, this is my first book, so I'm wondering if inserting a blank page to start on an odd page (like what `\cleardoublepage` does) in an ebook is a bad thing, since most ebooks show one page at a time, so blank pages would be annoying? Do you have an opinion?

Comment: I think one page is goog for ebooks. Every ebook reader display them differently anyway, so you cannot tell if the page is odd, it will be always different, depending on the user's device.