# Is it possible to use skak package to generate document in epub or mobi format?

Tags: chess, skak, epub

I use skak to generate a beautiful chess book in PDF format. Unfortunately, Amazon Kindle does not import the PDF well. So, I have to make a Kindle friendly formatted book such as epub.

Is it possible to use the same latex source document to generate epub? If not, is there any other latex package that can help generate epub document for a chess book?

Here's the minimum sample document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=[RGB]{41,41,41},
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Chess},
    bookmarks=true,
}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\showmoverOn
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{My title}
\maketitle                
\tableofcontents                        
\mainmatter                             
\author{Sudheer}

\chapter{Introduction}
\newgame
\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 g6 3.Bc4 Bg7 4.Ng5 e6}
\showboard

\end{document}
```

I am compiling using these steps:

```
 latex minimum.tex 
 dvips minimum.dvi 
 ps2pdf minimum.ps
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Probably [Use LaTeX to produce Epub](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1551/106162) is a good starting place to look.

Comment: I thought that kindle can't handle epub. Or has this changed?

Comment: I don't know about `skak` package, but I know that `xskak` has been used for ePub generation using `tex4ebook`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307252/2891.

Comment: @michal.h21 skak and xskak use the same font setup (I wrote chessfss first for skak and Torben changed skak to use it). So the font side should be ok. Boards and user interface are different.

Comment: "We support unzipped ePub files. Before uploading, we recommend validating the file with Kindle Gen or Kindle Previewer." - https://kdp.amazon.com/help/topic/A2GF0UFHIYG9VQ

Comment: Anyway, could you provide some minimal sample document? It is hard to say without something we can test.

Comment: michal.h21, I have edited the question to include the minimum document and commands to compile the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tex4ebook` to create the `ePub` or `mobi` ebooks. It uses `tex4ht` for the conversion. `tex4ht` doesn't support `skak` package out of the box, but it is easily configurable, so we can add the support ourselves.

There are  two things which needs to be addressed: the chess figures in the text, and the chessboards. The chess figures can be converted as Unicode characters, the chessboards must be converted as images.

The figures use a special font, which needs to be configured in `tex4ht`. Save the following text as `SkakNew.htf` and put it to the directory with your document:

```
SkakNew  32 121
'' ''     32
'!' ''     33
'&#x201D;' ''     34
'#' ''  35
'$' ''  36
'%' ''  37
'&#x0026;' ''  38
'&#x2019;' ''     39
'&#x0028;' ''  40
'&#x0029;' ''  41
'*' ''  42
'+' ''  43
',' ''  44
'-' ''  45
'.' ''  46
'/' ''     47
'0' ''  48
'1' ''  49
'2' ''  50
'3' ''  51
'4' ''  52
'5' ''  53
'6' ''  54
'7' ''  55
'8' ''  56
'9' ''  57
':' ''  58
';' ''  59
'&#x00A1;' ''     60
'=' ''  61
'&#x00BF;' ''     62
'?' ''  63
'@' ''  64
'&#x2192;' ''  65
'&#x2657;' ''  66
'&#x2191;' ''  67
'&#x2299;' ''  68
'&#x25B3;' ''  69
'&#x25A1;' ''  70
'&#x21D7;' ''  71
'&#x21D4;' ''  72
'&#x229e;' ''  73
'&#x2573;' ''  74
'&#x2654;' ''  75
'&#x27c2;' ''  76
'&#x226A;' ''  77
'&#x2658;' ''  78
'&#x226B;' ''  79
'&#x2161;' ''  80
'&#x2655;' ''  81
'&#x2656;' ''  82
'&#x003e;' ''  83
'&#x2295;' ''  84
'&#x25CB;' ''  85
'&#x21C6;' ''  86
'W' ''  87
'&times;' ''  88
'Y' ''  89
'Z' ''  90
'&#x005B;' ''  91
'&#x201C;' ''     92
'&#x005D;' ''  93
'&#x02C6;' ''     94
'&#x02D9;' ''     95
'&#x2018;' ''     96
'&#x29c9;' ''  97
'&#x2313;' ''  98
'&#x00b1;' ''  99
'&#x2982;' ''  100
'&#x2213;' ''  101
'&#x2a72;' ''  102
'&#x2a71;' ''  103
'h' ''  I cannot find it, it is plus followed by minus
'i' ''  minus followed by plus
'&#x003d;' ''  106
'k' ''  107
'l' ''  108
'#' ''  109
'n' ''  110
'o' ''  111
'p' ''  112
'q' ''  113
'r' ''  114
's' ''  115
't' ''  116
'u' ''  117
'v' ''  118
'w' ''  119
'x' ''  120
'y' ''  121
SkakNew  32 121
```

The images for chess boards can be requested with the following configuration. Save it as `skak.4ht` and save it to your document's dir as well:

```
\NewConfigure{SkakBoard}{2}

\pend:def\showboard{\a:SkakBoard}
\append:def\showboard{\b:SkakBoard}

\Configure{SkakBoard}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}

\endinput
```

It just patches command `\showboard` to include special `tex4ht` commands which convert enclosed content as images.

You can compile your document to `mobi` using the following comamand. Note that you need to have `kindlegen` installed:

```
 tex4ebook -f mobi  minimum.tex
```

The result is following, shown in Calibre:

[image]

To get better picture quality, you can try to add the following line to the `skak.4ht` file (before `\endinput`):

```
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
```

It will request the graphics in the `svg` format:

[image]

One last note: I got invalid `ePub` file because you used `\author` after `maketitle`, you should put it before it.

Edit:

If you want to use more commands which print to one canvas, you need to enclose them in custom environment, whose contents will be converted as an image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=[RGB]{41,41,41},
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Chess},
    bookmarks=true,
}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\showmoverOn
\newenvironment{mymoves}{}{}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{My title}
\author{Sudheer}
\maketitle                
\tableofcontents                        
\mainmatter                             

\chapter{Introduction}
\newgame
\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 g6 3.Bc4 Bg7 4.Ng5 e6}
\begin{mymoves}
\showboard
\printarrow{a1}{a8}
\end{mymoves}

\end{document}
```

The important part here is:

```
\begin{mymoves}
\showboard
\printarrow{a1}{a8}
\end{mymoves}
```

You can configure the `mymoves` environment in the config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\ConfigureEnv{mymoves}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

Note that it seems that this sample needs to use the SVG output, it seems that `dvipng` doesn't support some PostScript.

The result:

[image]

Comment: michal.h21, Thanks. That helps a lot already. The image you have posted is better than the one I generated. The one I generated has a white line(arc) on top left corner of dark squares. I wonder what is wrong in my setup. I copied and pasted the configs you mentioned. https://ibb.co/e4DXfk is an example

Comment: @Sudheer it is possible that you have older version of `tex4ht`, it uses different way to generate the images. it should be fixed in the updated TeX Live.

Comment: I noticed one other issue, the board ornaments do not appear in .mobi. Arrows, circles, etc do not appear.

Comment: @Sudheer do you have any example?

Comment: yes, after \showboard just the command: \printarrow{a1}{a8}. Here's the PDF screenshot: https://ibb.co/eCzm6Q

Comment: michal.h21, the version of tex4ht I have is: Epoch : 6 Version  : svn41440 Release : 33.fc25.1. Is it too old?

Comment: I see. The problem is that the picture is saved from the `\showboard` command, the `\printarrow` can't touch it. One solution is to enclose all drawing commands in an environment, whose all contents will be converted to image. I will update the answer.

Comment: I installed the latest texlive and the image quality of the board has improved.

Comment: @Sudheer I've updated my answer with example how it is possible to support the `\printarrow`

Comment: In which file should the preamble config go? How do you use that config file while compiling the document? When using the new configuration, should skak.4ht remain as it is?

Comment: @Sudheer save it as myconfig.cfg and compile using "-c" option, like "tex4ebook -f mobi -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58207/discussion-between-sudheer-and-michal-h21).