# Xskak and amazon ebook compatibility

Tags: pdf, xskak, ebook, kindle

I am using xskak 1.7 package developped by Ulrike Fischer. It's a very clean way to write my book about chess which is now online on amazon, thanks a lot for that !

I ve recently made an ebook version BUT got some big troubles when uploading the manuscript in pdf format to amazon kindle : the diagram don't load anymore.[image: Pdf output of my ebook].

Amazon result preview :

[image]

Should i convert my pdf to .docx format ?

Amazon website says : "We accept PDF files, but they can contain embedded formatting and/or images that don't convert well to eBooks. If you'd like to upload a PDF file for your book, preview it before you publish. If you see any issues or if your book doesn't look the way you want it to, we recommend converting your PDF to a Word document and formatting it according to our eBook Formatting Guide." but i didn't manage to success :(

Thanks for help,

Comment: I have some doubts that the kindle format can actually represent chess diagrams with fonts - unicode doesn't have code points for the needed symbols. So you probably would have to convert all diagrams to png, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307277/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was curious why I haven't added a `chessboard.4ht` yet and I found that I am still unable to patch the `\chessboard` command to produce an image.

Comment: @michal.h21 what is the problem? Is there anything I can do help you?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer maybe I am just tired, but it seems the board is constructed after the `\Picture` command is closed, so it ends as a string. Here are my test files: https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/293d567ce11e1f1eba0112d908a26245 (I've tried a similar configuration for `\chessboard` first, but the result was the same)

Comment: @michal.h21 I will try later.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. I should go sleep to