# Make4HT with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, tex4ht, make4ht

I have `LuaLaTeX` and it's working fine. But when i have converting LaTeX to HTML used `make4ht test.tex` it's showing error.

`make4ht -f html5+detect_engine test.tex`

`make4ht -l test.tex`

How to fix this?

MWE IS:

```
\documentclass{elife}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Grasp movement initiation and representation}

\author[1\authfn{1}]{J. Steven}
\author[2]{S. Manesesh}
\author[1*]{K. Alexanders}
\affil[1]{Department of Clinical and Movement Neurosciences, United Kingdom}
\affil[2]{Gatsby Computational Neuroscience Unit, United Kingdom}

\corr{k.alex@ucl.ac}{AC}

\presentadd[\authfn{1}]{Zanvyl Mind/Brain Institute, United States}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
We recorded single neurons in F1 and hold actions, and investigated the population-level differences could explain, please refer for each grasp (\FIG{Fig1Main}A) and \FIGSUPP[Fig1Main]{Fig1Supp} how overt movement is withheld during the latter condition.

\begin{figure}
\begin{fullwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Fig1}
\caption{During task. Top panels show pre-processed, rectified, and normalized average homepad and object displacement signals.}
\label{fig:Fig1Main}
\figsupp[EMG during all traces]{\textbf{(A.)} Execution traces are shown in \FIG{Fig1Main}.}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Fig1Supp}} \label{figsupp:Fig1Supp}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`E:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1:`. How to solve this error?

I have using `Windows` and `TeXLive2021`.

`elife` is available here: https://github.com/zhoupc/eLife_submission/blob/master/elife.cls

Comment: I get compilation error for this file even with `pdflatex`, the `\FIGSUPP` command is unknown. Isn't part of the document missing?

Comment: @michal.h21: `\FIGSUPP` is defined as: \newcommand{\FIGSUPP}[2][]{\ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\autoref{fig:#1}--}\autoref{figsupp:#2}}

Comment: Thanks. The output is still weird in the PDF output, but it compiles.

Comment: @michal.h21: I've adjusted LaTeX Template, and I would like to convert `LaTeX to HTML`.  I have refered `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344200/does-autoref-break-tex4ht` and cross-links are working except all `sections` are not convert to `html`.

Comment: @michal.h21: But when running `make4ht` first time running showing error: `\undefined \autoref` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the `elife` class loads Unicode-math package, which is not supported by TeX4ht. It even causes fatal error. To fix that, we need to create a special file that will prevent Unicode-math from loading, and define dummy version of `\setmathfont`.

Here is the file, `unicode-math-hooks.4ht`:

```
\:dontusepackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\NewDocumentCommand \setmathfont { O{} m O{} }{}

\endinput
```

We need to register this file in TeX4ht, using `usepackage.4ht`:

```
% usepackage.4ht (2021-12-14-13:43), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-12-14-13:43}

   \def\:temp{tex4ht}\ifx \:temp\@currname
   \:warning{\string\usepackage{tex4ht} again?}
   \def\:temp#1htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp \@filelist htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty!*?: %
\ifx \:temp\empty  \else
   \:warning{if
    \string\RequirePackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} was
    used try instead, repectively,
    \string\RequirePackage{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage{hyperref}}
\fi

\fi
\gdef\a:usepackage{\use:package ,!*?: }
\gdef\use:package#1,{%
   \if :#1:\def\:temp##1!*?: {}\else
      \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \@currname\:temp
             \def\:temp##1!*?: {\input usepackage.4ht  }%
      \else \let\:temp=\use:package \fi
   \fi \:temp}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex-chicago.sty}{biblatex-chicago-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{cleveref.sty}{cleveref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr.sty}{xr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr-hyper.sty}{xrhyper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{eso-pic.sty}{esopic-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{showframe.sty}{showframe-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{expl3.sty}{expl3-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{savetrees.sty}{savetrees-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty}%
{fontawesome5-utex-helper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5.sty}{fontawesome5-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex.sty}{biblatex-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xeCJK.sty}{xecjk-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{ctex.sty}{ctex-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{polyglossia.sty}{polyglossia-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontspec.sty}{fontspec-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{tikz.sty}{tikz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pdfbase.sty}{pdfbase-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperref.sty}{hyperref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{caption.sty}{caption-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{minted.sty}{minted-sty-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphics.sty}{graphics-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphbox.sty}{graphbox-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xcolor.sty}{xcolor-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{imakeidx.sty}{imakeidx-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fancyhdr.sty}{fancyhdr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{exerquiz.sty}{exerquiz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperxmp.sty}{hyperxmp-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{datetime2.sty}{datetime2-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{unicode-math.sty}{unicode-math-hooks.4ht}


\endinput
```

With this fix, you will not get a fatal error, but you will still get a compilation error caused by `elife`'s additions to `\maketitle`. We can fix this issue with `elife.4ht` file:

```
\def\:tempa{%
     \a:themetadata%
     \textbf{*For correspondence:}  \@correspondence\par
     \ifx\empty\@contribution\else
     \c:themetadata\bigskip\@contribution\d:themetadata\fi
     \ifx\empty\@presentaddress\else
     \e:themetadata\textbf{Present address: }\@presentaddress\f:themetadata\fi
     \bigskip
     \ifx\empty\@deceased\else\g:themetadata\@deceased\h:themetadata\fi
     \b:themetadata%
}

\HLet\themetadata\:tempa

% redefine \@author to include affiliations and other information
\def\:tempa{\a:authlist\ifx\AB@affillist\AB@empty\AB@author\else
      \ifnum\value{affil}>\value{Maxaffil}\def\rlap##1{##1}%
    \c:authlist\AB@authlist\d:authlist\themetadata\e:authlist\AB@affillist\f:authlist
    \else  \AB@authors\fi\fi\b:authlist}
\HLet\@author\:tempa

\NewConfigure{themetadata}{8}

\NewConfigure{authlist}{6}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
   \textcolor{eLifeLightBlue}{\large\bfseries\abstractname\space}
}{%   
}

\Hinput{elife}
\endinput
```

It inserts some configurable hooks that can be used to insert HTML code. Yu can configure these hooks in a `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

% configure environments in \maketitle
\Configure{authlist}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="authlist">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
{\HCode{<div>}}{\HCode{</div><div>}}{\HCode{</div><div>}}{\HCode{</div>}}

\Configure{themetadata}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="themetadata">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
{\HCode{<div>}}{\HCode{</div><div>}}{\HCode{</div><div>}}
{\HCode{</div><div>}}{\HCode{</div><div>}}{\HCode{</div>}}
\Css{.themetadata{font-size:0.8rem;}}

\def\IgnoreRule{\special{t4ht@\string_}}
\def\EndIgnoreRule{\special{t4ht@\string_\string_}}

\ConfigureEnv{abstract}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<section role="doc-abstract" class="abstract">\Hnewline}\IgnoreRule}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</section>\Hnewline}\EndIgnoreRule}{}{}

\Css{.authlist span{font-size:0.8rem;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

It should compile correctly now:

Comment: It's working fine, except `\section` and `figure cross-links` are not convert to `html`. I have updated the question. How to fix this errors?

Comment: @Balaji it is possible that more stuff needs fixes. I will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: How to convert `\section` tag to HTML? Could you please advise...