# make4ht, tikz and utf-8 encoding question

Tags: tikz-pgf, unicode, tex4ht, make4ht

Consider the following simple latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht-alt.def}\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386757/work-around-for-bug-in-pgf-when-used-with-htlatex
\begin{filecontents}{pgfsys-tex4ht-alt.def}
% Fix due to Michal Hoftich
\input pgfsys-tex4ht.def
\def\pgfsys@svg@newline{^^J}
\end{filecontents}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
         \foreach \x in {-3,...,3} {
            \draw(\x,0.25) --(\x,0)node[below]{$\x$};
          }
          \foreach \x in {-2.5,...,2.5} {
            \draw(\x,0.18) --(\x,0);
          }
          \draw[thick,<->](-3.5,0)--(3.5,0);
          \filldraw[blue](1.5,0) circle (1mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}

-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3

\end{document}
```

When run through `pdflatex` this produces the pdf image:

[image]

When run through `make4ht` this produces essentially the same html/svg image:

[image]

Unfortunately, this goes pear shaped when we run through the MWE through `make4ht -u`, using the utf-8 option, as we get:

[image]

The first two images are correct but there is an encoding/svg issue when using `make4ht -u` with the negative numbers appearing in the tikz code; more accurately, there is a problem with the minus sign. My real application uses utf-8 so dropping the `-u` switch is not really an option for me.

Any idea how to fix the last image when using `make4ht -u`?

I would think that you get the same error using a utf-8 encoding with `htlatex` but I prefer to use `make4ht` because it has a much nicer syntax.

[The use of the [filecontents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package in the MWE is to correct a bug in PGF that prevents tikz from playing nicely with tex4ht; see [Work around for bug in pgf when used with htlatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386757/work-around-for-bug-in-pgf-when-used-with-htlatex)
 for details. Run `pdflatex` on the MWE first otherwise `make4ht` will give an error because the file `pgfsys-tex4ht-alt.def` won't have been created yet.]

Comment: btw, have you seen another question from this weekend: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390594/2891 ? it seems that TikZ `/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=true` solves some problems with formatted text in nodes.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks@ I hadn't seen this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `pgfsys-tex4ht.def` sets the encoding of the SVG file to `iso-8859-1`:

```
 \pgfsys@invoke{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
```

This definition is hardwired in this file, so it cannot be really changed from the outside, we need to edit `pgfsys-tex4ht.def` directly.

We can use the following macros to get value of output encoding used by `tex4ht`:

```
\def\getEncoding#1charset=#2,#3\@nil{\if|#2|iso-8859-1\else#2\fi}
\def\htmlencoding{\expandafter\getEncoding\Preamble ,charset=,\@nil}
```

It uses `Latin1` by default, but it will detect `utf-8` with `-u` option of `make4ht`.

This is the full `pgfsys-tex4ht.def`:

```
% Copyright 2006 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/generic/pgf/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\ProvidesFileRCS $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-tex4ht.def,v 1.25 2013/08/06 17:46:08 tantau Exp $



% Driver commands for tex4ht

%
% Load common pdf commands:
%
\input pgfsys-common-svg.def

%
% tex4ht-specific stuff:
%
\def\pgfsys@invoke#1{\pgf@sys@fail{svg code in preamble}}
\def\pgfsys@body@invoke#1{\HCode{#1}}

\newcount\pgf@sys@svg@picnum

\def\pgfsys@pictureboxsynced#1{%
  \pgfsys@beginscope\pgflowlevelsynccm\box#1\pgfsys@endscope%
}


%%
%% initial support of Mathml and xhtml inside svg through the svg:foreignelement tag
%%
%% it'll allow us to have complicated text nodes in the tex4ht driver
%%


%Example  (to improve the display, you have to use css)
%
%\tikzpicture[svg text only=false]
%\draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0pt,draw] {tight}
%(0cm,2em) node[inner sep=5pt,draw] {loose}
%(0cm,4em) node[fill=red!20] {default};
%\draw (3,0) node[inner sep=0pt,draw] {TIGHT}
%(3cm,2em) node[inner sep=5pt,draw] {LOOSE}
%(3cm,4em) node[fill=red!20] {DEFAULT};
%\draw (6,0) node[inner sep=0pt,draw] {$tight$}
%(6cm,2em) node[inner sep=5pt,draw] {$loose$}
%(6cm,4em) node[fill=red!20] {$default$};
%\draw (9,0) node[inner sep=0pt,draw] {$TIGHT$}
%(9cm,2em) node[inner sep=5pt,draw] {$LOOSE$}
%(9cm,4em) node[fill=red!20] {$Default$};
%\endtikzpicture
%
% you can use the options "svg text css=filename", "svg text id=idname", "svg text class=classname" to customize the display through the use of css
%







%\def\pgfsys@beginpicture{%
% % \Configure{[]}{$}{$}   these two lines aren't needed for tex4ht and moreother they produce errors with plain tex !
% % \Configure{()}{$}{$}
% \Configure{$$}{}{}{}%$$
% \Configure{$}{}{}{}%$
%  \Configure{SUB}{\HCode{<tspan baseline-shift="sub">}}{\HCode{</tspan>}}
%  \Configure{SUP}{\HCode{<tspan baseline-shift="sub">}}{\HCode{</tspan>}}
%  \Configure{SUBSUP}{}{}{}
%  \Configure{htf} 
%    {0}{+}{<tspan font-family="}
%    {\%s}{" font-size="\%s}{}{}
%    {">}{</tspan>}
%}



%\def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
%  % undo:
%  \Configure{htf}{0}{+}{<span\Hnewline
%     class="}{\%s}{-\%s}{x-x-\%d}{}{">}{</span>}
%}

\def\pgfsys@svg@newline{\Hnewline}

% we don't want tex4ht putting <p> and </p> tags automatically in our svg code and causing invalid xhtml in our svg pictures
\newif\ifpgfsys@CssIncluded@\pgfsys@CssIncluded@false
\def\pgfsys@beginpicture{% 
  \EndP\HtmlParOff
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=false}%
  % text only nodes are the default. Advantage : pure svg pictures are
  % the default, nicer for text only nodes.  
  % Disadvantages : this rendering methods produce more invalid or degraded svg pictures than with the foreignelement tag
  %% we use css to control the display of foreignelement rendered text nodes
  \ifpgfsys@CssIncluded@
  \else
    \Css{
      .foreignobject {%
        line-height:100\%;
        font-size:120\%; % this is the trick....a font of size 100% in
                         % a box scaled down to half size makes it a
                         % half size font. 
                         % you'll have to double the size of things
                         % that you want to have a regular size in
                         % this half-scaled box though  
        font-family:STIXgeneral,Times,Symbol,cmr10,CMSY10,CMEX10;%
        % can't wait for the stix font...the cmr10, etc font are
        % available from the mozilla site, times and symbols should be
        % okey  
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        % background-color:\#12ff55;  usefull for debugging positioning
        text-align:center; % good for centered text nodes...will have to improve that later on...with more integration with pgf options for text nodes
      }
    }%
    \Css{%
      math {%, math[mode="inline"] {
        vertical-align:baseline;
        line-height:100\%;
        font-size:100\%;
        font-family:STIXGeneral,Times,Symbol, cmr10,cmsy10,cmex10,cmmi10;
        font-style: normal;
        margin:0;
        % background-color:\#99ff99;
        padding:0;
      }%
    }%
    \pgfsys@CssIncluded@true
  \fi
}%

\def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
  \HtmlParOn
  \par% FIXME : was '\Par' but that seems to be undefined!?
}%

\def\getEncoding#1charset=#2,#3\@nil{\if|#2|iso-8859-1\else#2\fi}
\def\htmlencoding{\expandafter\getEncoding\Preamble ,charset=,\@nil}
% this is okay for both rendering methods for text nodes (mtext or foreignelement)...
\def\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox#1{%
  \global\advance\pgf@sys@svg@picnum by 1\relax%
  % Ok, compute width/height
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@picminx%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@picminy%
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@picmaxx%
  \pgf@yb=\pgf@picmaxy%
  \pgf@x=\pgf@xb%
  \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@xa%
  \pgf@y=\pgf@yb%
  \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@ya%
  \ifdim\pgf@y<1pt%
    \pgf@y=1pt%
  \fi%
  \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%  
  \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%  
  \pgfsysprotocol@flushcurrentprotocol%
  \HCode{<object data="\jobname-\the\pgf@sys@svg@picnum.svg" width="}%
  % Calculate pixel coordinates (this does not really make sense, but
  % we have to do it anyway). Assume 96dpi.
  \pgf@x=1.3333333\pgf@x%
  \pgf@y=1.3333333\pgf@y%
  % Add one pixel for security:
  \advance\pgf@x by1pt%
  \advance\pgf@y by1pt%
  \pgf@sys@pt\pgf@x%
  \pgfsysprotocol@flushcurrentprotocol%
  \pgfsys@invoke{" height="}%
  \pgf@sys@pt\pgf@y%
  \pgfsysprotocol@flushcurrentprotocol%
  \pgfsys@invoke{" type="image/svg+xml"><p>SVG-Viewer needed.</p></object>}%
  \special{t4ht>\jobname-\the\pgf@sys@svg@picnum.svg}%
  %%%%%%%% This is necessary to control the svg through css
  \pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/tex4ht node/css/.get=\pgfsys@foreignobject@css
  }%
  \pgfsys@invoke{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="\htmlencoding" standalone="no"?>\Hnewline% added that
  <?xml-stylesheet href="\pgfsys@foreignobject@css.css" type="text/css"?>\Hnewline}% added that 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% maybee I should add an option to change the css, for the whole picture
  \pgfsys@invoke{<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="\the\pgf@xc"
    height="\the\pgf@yc" viewBox="}%
  \pgf@sys@pt{\pgf@xa}\pgf@sys@pt{\pgf@ya}\pgf@sys@pt{\pgf@xc}\pgf@sys@pt{\pgf@yc}%
  \pgfsysprotocol@flushcurrentprotocol%
  \pgf@ya=-\pgf@ya%
  \pgfsys@invoke{">\Hnewline  <g transform="translate(0,}
  \pgf@sys@pt\pgf@yb\pgfsysprotocol@flushcurrentprotocol%
  \pgfsys@invoke{) scale(1,-1) translate(0,}%
  \pgf@sys@pt\pgf@ya\pgfsysprotocol@flushcurrentprotocol%
  \pgfsys@invoke{)">\Hnewline }%
  %
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@shift@baseline\relax%
  \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@picminy\relax%
  %
  %
  \advance\pgf@picmaxy by-\pgf@picminy\relax% maxy is now the height
  \advance\pgf@picmaxx by-\pgf@picminx\relax% maxx is now the width
  \setbox#1=\hbox{\hskip-\pgf@picminx\lower\pgf@picminy\box#1}%
  \ht#1=\pgf@picmaxy%
  \wd#1=\pgf@picmaxx%
  \dp#1=0pt%
  \leavevmode
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@trimleft@final\relax  \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt \else\kern\pgf@xa\fi
  \raise-\pgf@ya\box#1%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@trimright@final\relax \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt \else\kern\pgf@xa\fi
  \pgfsys@invoke{</g>\Hnewline </svg>\Hnewline }%
  \special{t4ht<\jobname-\the\pgf@sys@svg@picnum.svg}%
}%

%% we'll use this hbox for the mtext rendering method (the "text only=true" option)
\def\pgfsys@hbox#1{%
  \pgf@x=.5\wd#1%
  \ifx\tikz@textcolor\relax\else\ifx\tikz@textcolor\@undefined\else%
    \ifx\tikz@textcolor\pgfutil@empty%
      \pgfsetfillcolor{.}%
    \else%
      \pgfsetfillcolor{\tikz@textcolor}%
    \fi%
  \fi\fi% tweak for TikZ
  \HCode{<text
    style="stroke:none"
    transform="scale(1,-1) translate(\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x},0)"
    text-anchor="middle"
  }%
  \ifpgfutil@format@is@latex%
    \ifx\f@size\pgfutil@empty%
    \else%
      \HCode{ font-size="\f@size"}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \HCode{>\Hnewline }%
    \wd#1=0pt%
    \ht#1=0pt%
    \dp#1=0pt%
    \box#1
  \HCode{</text>\Hnewline }%
}%

%% we save this definition
\let\pgfsys@mtext@hbox\pgfsys@hbox

%% we have to use some "evil" ^^ tex4ht hackery
% tex4ht hackery
{% grouping necessary cause we change the catcode of ":"
  \catcode`:=11\relax
  %%% this is necessary to calculate the size of text nodes with
  %%% inline maths  
  % (it is an improvement of tex4ht, got to ask eitan gurary if he
  % could put it in the tex4ht code) 
  \gdef\DviMathAlt{%
    \a:DviMath\leavevmode \MathClass
    \ht:special{t4ht@(}\hbox\bgroup{\expandafter\ifx\csname
      ht:everypar\endcsname\relax\expandafter\everypar\else
      \expandafter\ht:everypar\fi{}\leavevmode\ht:special{t4ht@)}}\DviSend 
  }%
  % these are configures for the foreignelement rendering method of text nodes : we let tex4ht write xhtml and mathml in the svg picture
  % 
  \gdef\pgfsys@foreignobject@configure{%
    \Configure{$}{\Configure{@math}{%\a:mathml
        display="inline" }\DviMathAlt}{\EndDviMath}{}%%% we REALLY need to use \DviMathAlt here instead of \DviMath see above remark
    \Configure{$$}{\Configure{@math}{%\a:mathml
        display="block" }\IgnorePar
      \ifvmode\else \HCode{<!--tex4ht:inline-->}\fi\EndP
      \DviMath}{\EndDviMath\ShowPar\pgfsys@foreignobject@par{\csname HCondtrue\endcsname\noindent}
    }{\DisplayMathtrue}%
    \Configure{SUB}{\Send{BACK}{<\a:mathml msub><\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>}%
      \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base}{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\TG</\a:mathml msub\Hnewline>}%
    \Configure{SUP}{\Send{BACK}{<\a:mathml msup><\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>}%
      \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base}{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\TG</\a:mathml msup\Hnewline>}%
    \Configure{SUBSUP}{\Send{BACK}{<\a:mathml msubsup><\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>}%
      \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base}{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>\trap:base}{\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\TG</\a:mathml msubsup\Hnewline>}%
    \Configure{htf}{0}{+}{<span\Hnewline
      class="}{\%s}{-\%s}{x-x-\%d}{}{">}{</span>}%
  }%
  \global\let\pgfsys@foreignobject@par=\par % use this instead of \par
                                % -- \Configure is no \long macro (at
                                % least in one of the older
                                % versions). 

  % these are the configures for the mtext rendering method of text
  % nodes : we turn everything into regular character (don't want math
  % modes or subsup) 
  % and we hope it works (it doesn't if the text nodes aren't simple) 
  \gdef\pgfsys@mtext@configure{%
    % no configures for \(\) and \[\] those might be needed for
    % context or Latex. Let me know ! 
    \Configure{$$}{}{}{}% no block maths
    \Configure{$}{}{}{}%$ no inline maths
    \Configure{SUB}{\HCode{<tspan baseline-shift="sub">}}{\HCode{</tspan>}}%
    \Configure{SUP}{\HCode{<tspan baseline-shift="sub">}}{\HCode{</tspan>}}%
    \Configure{SUBSUP}{}{}{}% not both sub and sup
    \Configure{htf} {0}{+}{<tspan font-family="}{\%s}{" font-size="\%s}{}{}{">}{</tspan>}%
  }%
}%

% a counter to produce unique ids for each text node rendered with foreign element
\newcount\pgf@sys@svg@nodenum


% pgfutil@minipage
%
%  I had to change it to make it play nice with the way tex4ht puts <p> and <\p> tags 
%

\newif\ifpgfsys@textonly
\def\pgfutil@minipage[#1]#2{%
  \hbox to#2\bgroup
    \hsize=#2\relax
    \vbox\bgroup    
% though it works, I'm desabling the above mentioned hack to make tex4ht behave with <p> <\p>, because it blurps the positioning 
% (I''l try to fix that later, it's a css thing)
%
%    \ifpgfsys@textonly\else\HtmlParOn\fi
%
% \noindent is better as it doesn't produce indentation AND it makes you leave vertical mode
    \noindent%\leavevmode 
}%
\def\pgfutil@endminipage{%
%  same thing here
%
%  \ifpgfsys@textonly\else\EndP\HtmlParOff\fi
  \egroup\egroup
}%


% I'll have to fix those names later
\newbox\pgfsys@foreignobject@Box
\newdimen\pgf@s
\newdimen\pgf@t
% this is the alternate hbox routine that renders text nodes through the foreignobject tag 
\def\pgfsys@foreignobject@hbox#1{%
  % Compute box y translation  (x translation is correct).
  \pgf@y=-\ht#1\relax
  \HCode{<g transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@y}) % got to translate in y
    scale(0.5,0.5)">\Hnewline}% scaling work around (damn dumb browsers !)
  % Compute box size (scaled 2 times)
  % this is necessary to make the browser scale the font down 50% (the STUPID browsers won't make font-size:50% happen, 
  % so we have to work around this by making svg scale the things down 50%, doubling the size of the text node frame (i.e. no changement there)
  \pgf@x=2\wd#1\relax
  \pgf@y=2\ht#1\relax
  \advance\pgf@y by 2\dp#1\relax
  % this is to adjust the y translation to compensate for the differences between the TeX and the Html models for lines
  \setbox\pgfsys@foreignobject@Box=\hbox{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    $abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZf_1^1\overline D)_1^1\vec i\vec j$}%
  \pgf@t=\ht#1\relax
  \advance\pgf@t by -\ht\pgfsys@foreignobject@Box\relax
  \pgf@s=\pgf@t\relax
  \advance\pgf@s by \dp#1\relax
  \advance\pgf@s by -\dp\pgfsys@foreignobject@Box\relax
  \ifnum\pgf@s>0\relax
    \pgf@s=0pt
    \pgf@t=0pt
  \else
    \advance \pgf@y by -2\pgf@s\relax
    \pgf@t=2\pgf@t\relax    
  \fi
  % 
  \HCode{<foreignObject x="0" y="\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@t}"
    width="\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}" height="\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@y}">}%
  % this is to make use of the css, class and id options through which you can control the way things display
  \pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/tex4ht node/css/.get=\pgfsys@foreignobject@css,%
    /pgf/tex4ht node/class/.get=\pgfsys@foreignobject@class,%
    /pgf/tex4ht node/id/.get=\pgfsys@foreignobject@id
  }%
  \HCode{<head>\Hnewline
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\pgfsys@foreignobject@css.css" />\Hnewline
    </head>\Hnewline
    % I'll have to look into this, perhaps there are better
    % doctype....&nbsp; aren't recognised and produces invalid svg
    % pictures a workaround (not implemented yet) would be to make
    % them into entities of the svg picture. 
    <body id="\pgfsys@foreignobject@id" class="\pgfsys@foreignobject@class" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >\Hnewline 
    <div>\Hnewline
  }%
  \box#1%
  \HCode{%
    </div>\Hnewline
    </body>\Hnewline
    </foreignObject>\Hnewline
  }%
  % debug positioning not needed but it would be nice to let it there to control things later on
  % \HCode{<rect x="0" y="0" width="\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}" height="\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@y}" 
  %   style="fill:yellow;stroke:red; fill-opacity:0.5;stroke-opacity:0.5"/>}
  \HCode{</g>\Hnewline}%
  \global\advance\pgf@sys@svg@nodenum by 1\relax    
}%

% the options and the code that controls it all (switches between \pgfsys@mtext@hbox and \pgfsys@foreignelement@hbox)

\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/.cd,
  tex4ht node/escape/.is choice,
  tex4ht node/escape/false/.code={\let\pgfsys@hbox\pgfsys@mtext@hbox\pgfsys@mtext@configure\pgfsys@textonlytrue},
  tex4ht node/escape/true/.code={\let\pgfsys@hbox\pgfsys@foreignobject@hbox\pgfsys@foreignobject@configure\pgfsys@textonlyfalse},
  tex4ht node/css/.initial=\jobname,
  tex4ht node/class/.initial=foreignobject,
  tex4ht node/id/.initial=\jobname\the\pgf@sys@svg@picnum-\the\pgf@sys@svg@nodenum
}%






% this might be needed 
%\font\SvgText=cmr10\relax




% There is something rellay wrong with the way "%" chars are used in here... you should code "}%" to avoid unnecessary spaces
% and it is unnecessary to code \cs%
% got to be carefull with numbers though, cf the texbook...2\relax and 2 % are okey

\def\pgfsys@outerinvoke{\ifpgfpicture\expandafter\pgfsys@invoke\else\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble\fi}

\def\pgfsys@shadingoutsidepgfpicture#1{\pgf@sys@fail{svg code in preamble}}
\def\pgfsys@shadinginsidepgfpicture#1{\pgf@sys@fail{svg code in preamble}}

\def\pgfsys@body@shadingoutsidepgfpicture#1{%
  \begingroup%
    #1%
    \setbox\pgfpic=\hbox to0pt{%
      \pgfsys@beginpicture%
        \pgfsys@beginscope%
          \pgf@sys@svg@sh@defs%
          \pgf@sys@svg@sh%
        \pgfsys@endscope%
      \pgfsys@endpicture%
      \hss%  
    }%
    \pgf@process{\pgf@sys@svg@pos}%
    \pgf@picminx=0pt%
    \pgf@picminy=0pt%
    \pgf@picmaxx=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@picmaxy=\pgf@y%
    \def\pgf@shift@baseline{0pt}%
    \pgfsys@typesetpicturebox\pgfpic%
  \endgroup%
}

\def\pgfsys@body@shadinginsidepgfpicture#1{%
  #1%
  \pgf@sys@svg@sh@defs% hmmm....
  \pgf@process{\pgf@sys@svg@pos}
  \pgf@xa=-.5\pgf@x%
  \pgf@ya=-.5\pgf@y%
  \pgfsysprotocol@literal{<g transform="translate(\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@xa},\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@ya})">\Hnewline}%
  \pgf@sys@svg@sh%
  \pgfsysprotocol@literal{</g>\Hnewline}%
}


\ifpgfutil@format@is@latex
  % Protect against color.4ht evil meddling with xcolor:
  \RequirePackage{xcolor}
  \let\pgf@xcolor@declaredcolor=\@declaredcolor
  \let\pgf@xcolor@undeclaredcolor=\@undeclaredcolor
\fi

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\pgfsys@invoke=\pgfsys@body@invoke
  \let\pgfsys@shadingoutsidepgfpicture=\pgfsys@body@shadingoutsidepgfpicture
  \let\pgfsys@shadinginsidepgfpicture=\pgfsys@body@shadinginsidepgfpicture
  \ifpgfutil@format@is@latex
    \let\pgf@texht@declaredcolor=\@declaredcolor
    \let\pgf@texht@undeclaredcolor=\@undeclaredcolor
    \def\@declaredcolor{\ifpgfpicture\expandafter\pgf@xcolor@declaredcolor\else\expandafter\pgf@texht@declaredcolor\fi}
    \def\@undeclaredcolor{\ifpgfpicture\expandafter\pgf@xcolor@undeclaredcolor\else\expandafter\pgf@texht@undeclaredcolor\fi}
  \fi
  \def\pgfutil@color{\pgfsetcolor}
  % \ConfigureEnv{pgfpicture}{}{}{}{} there is no environment in plain TeX and this produces errors
  % this might be needed for context or latex though....let me know !
}%

\endinput


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% End:
```

The `SVG` is now rendered correctly:

[image]

Comment: Michal, thank you as always. I can repackage your solution to fit my needs. It is too long for a comment so I will post it as a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Michal's solution answers my question perfectly. For my use-case I need to repackage it slightly as I want to automatically apply this from within a  document class file for a package, so editing `pgfsys-tex4ht.def` is not an option for me. As this is too long for a comment I give the details here but this is really only a small variation on Michal's ideas.

To apply Michal's "patch" automatically we extend the ideas from [Work around for bug in pgf when used with htlatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386757/work-around-for-bug-in-pgf-when-used-with-htlatex) by making a new file `pgfsys-tex4ht-alt.def` that contains:

```
% Two fixes to pgfsys-tex4ht.def due to Michal Hoftich
\input pgfsys-tex4ht.def

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386757
\def\pgfsys@svg@newline{^^J}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390421
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}% for \patchcmd
\def\getEncoding#1charset=#2,#3\@nil{\if|#2|iso-8859-1\else#2\fi}
\def\htmlencoding{\expandafter\getEncoding\Preamble ,charset=,\@nil}
\patchcmd{\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox}{iso-8859-1}{\htmlencoding}{}{}
```

The first lines here fix the `\Hnewline` bug from [Work around for bug in pgf when used with htlatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386757/work-around-for-bug-in-pgf-when-used-with-htlatex) and the last section is the code from Michal's solution which is applied using `\patchcmd` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

I want the "patched" version of `pgfsys-tex4ht.def` to be loaded automatically by my document class whenever the (optional) class option `tikz` is given. This is achieved by the following lines in the class file:

```
\newif\ifTikz\Tikzfalse
\DeclareOption{tikz}{\Tikztrue}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

\ifTikz
   % hack to fix two pgf bugs - apply only when when using tex4ht
   \ifdefined\HCode
     \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht-alt.def}
   \fi
   \RequirePackage{tikz}
\fi
```

With this in place [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [tex4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht) will play more happily together.

Comment: This is nice trick with the `\patchcmd`.

Comment: @michal.h21 I think that I learned this trick on TeX.SX from one of egreg's answers...