# latexml - It can't find scrartcl

Tags: latexml

I'm trying to convert a LaTeX document (with lots of `\input`) into HTML:

```
latexml --includestyles document.tex
```

The warning I got:

```
Warning:missing_file:scrartcl Can't find binding for class scrartcl (using OmniBus)
```

Comment: tex4ht supports `scrartcl`. try `make4ht -u document.tex html5`

Comment: @michal.h21 Error encountered: `! Undefined control sequence.` 
`\pgfsys@svg@newline ->\Hnewline`

Comment: it is caused by a bug in `TikZ`. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386775/2891 for some discussion about possible workarounds

Comment: @michal.h21 Wow. Is there a way (free/paid) I can convert `.pdf` perfectly into `.docx` instead? I tried Acrobat DC, works even with complex `tcolorbox`. I thought Word would take in HTML better than it takes in PDF.

Comment: I don't know. You would lose all structural information (sections, footnotes, lists) in PDF to DOCX conversion. `tex4ht` can convert to `ODT` format which Word supports, but I am not sure how it will handle the `tcolorboxes`.

Answer (score 3):

I never used latexml, but it seems that it needs a »binding« for every used documentclass and package. See e.g. here: https://github.com/kpj/LaTeXML_Bindings_WIP/blob/master/bindings/mathtools.sty.ltxml

And your error message probably hints to a missing binding file for scrartcl. Missing bindings for KOMA-script (scrartcl is a part of it) are discussed here:
https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues/915

So you are out of luck, as it seems.