# htlatex Defines a Command Then Chokes on it

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX document into a HTML document but I keep hitting the same problem. When I compile (using the command `htlatex .\scratch.tex myhtml`), I get the following output:

```
G:\PhD\Thesis 3\Scratch> htlatex .\scratch.tex myhtml

G:\PhD\Thesis 3\Scratch>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode myhtml.a.b.c.\input  .\scratch.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6800 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> ...tother\HCode myhtml.a.b.c.\input  .\scratch
                                                  .tex
```

From this output the problem doesn't seam to be anything to do with the document (and the error is the same whatever the document is), rather it's a bug in tex4ht, but for reference `scratch.tex` is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Text text.
\end{document}
```

It seams that tex4ht is trying to define a command (`\HCode`) then run it before running the actual document, but for some reason the definition fails to take hold.

Updating MikTeX didn't change anything. From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185349/error-using-pgfsysdriver-with-tex4ht-only-shows-up-with-texlive-2014-ok-with-t), a similar problem with tex4ht was solved by altering one of the `.def` files that tex4ht uses. But I don't know which file is causing this error or how to fix it.

So, my two questions are: 1) what causes this error, and 2) which file would I need to change to fix it. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 10 64-bit, if that helps.

Comment: why do you use `htlatex .\scratch.tex`? it tries to execute the `\scratch` command. You can either use `htlatex scratch.tex` or `htlatex ./scratch.tex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to run `htlatex scratch.tex myhtml` and not `htlatex .\scratch.tex myhtml` - the `.\` confuses the compiler, and it thinks that you're trying to run the command `\scratch`. Thanks to michal.h21 for pointing this out.

A better solution is to use make4ht, which doesn't choke on the `.\`.

I should note that `.\scratch.tex` is what you get when you use the PowerShell autocomplete feature.

Comment: I am not on Windows, so cannot test it, but does `make4ht .\scratch.tex` work? make4ht is a replacement for htlatex with much more features.

Comment: Yes it does. I didn't know that make4ht existed.

Comment: you should take a look then, it fixes lot of `htlatex` issues, file name support is one of them

Comment: I recommend you just use `make4ht` for everything. You can still use the same options as before, but `make4ht` has many other functionalities. That is what I use now for all my builds.